# Concatenation - How to concatenate text with date

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to concatenate text in 1st column and date in 2nd column together.. How do i do that...?

I tried using last run on but it actually holds good for only date concatenation. howeer our requiremnets is text in the 1st column and date in the second column to be concatenated

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please share with us the formula you have already tried and what error message you are getting.

Comment: You haven't specified what software you are using. Without that, it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

To `CONCATENATE` using a date, you need to turn it into text within the formula using the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58) function.  For this answer I am using `A1` as the text value and `B1` as the date value.

If I attempt a standard formula;

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
```

It results is the date serial in the results.

[image]

Using the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58) function we can turn the date into text and it can then be combined with the text from `A1`.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Adjust the date format accordingly to suite your needs. If you need a space between the two items simply add `" "` to the `CONCATENATE` string.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ", TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```